# Example of NCP Address

Tags: internet

I'm looking to provide an example of an NCP (Network Control Protocol) address for a scholarly article that I'm writing.

The NCP was the protocol that was used by the ARPANet and which was introduced in [RFC 33](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc33).

The RFC says that hosts were addressed using a 40 bit address with the first 24 bits identifying a user, the next 8 bits addressing a host and the final 8 bits being just 8 bits that the host could use however it liked to address a process on the machine (these were early mainframes after all!).

I can't find any indication though of how people actually wrote these NCP addresses at the time and the only example in the RFC, X'0100050107', I can't quite figure out.

Does anyone know how they were written/formatted?

(Of course, I'm tempted to just write something like 192.192.192.192.82; but I'm concerned this would be an anachronism).

Comment: Wait so as a researcher, I'm not allowed to ask questions? But, if I had just said I'm an interested person, I would have been able to ask the question?!?!? This is why people hate the Overflow pages and avoid asking a question unless it is absolutely necessary lol

Comment: All right, I've removed the off-topic request for resources and am reopening the question - note that *historical trivia that is trivial/irrelevant to modern networking* is also off topic here. Let's see where we get.

Comment: I know pleasantries are also forbidden on most of the overflow boards, but since I've already bent the rules, I'm going to do it again and thank you! You solved my problem below lol! I didn't think to check if it were hexadecimal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ten-digit notation is hexadecimal, as indicating with the leading *X*. Each hexadecimal digit represents four bits - ten digits of four bits = 40 bits.